# How to fix these parser errors that i am getting for my lazyvim installation on neovim

Tags: parsing, lua, tui, neovim-plugin, treesitter

I have been trying to install the lazyvim config for my neovim and since i am very very new to the feild of TUI i don't have any clue on what's going on with my neovim, To be specific when i run the :checkhealth command i get thrown with a pool of parser errors, like these [here is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quM3o.png)
please help me I am stuck on this since 3 days

since i already informed i am a full newbie and going through the config files and different lua files and git documentations i don't know what to add where

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/wiki/Windows-support#:%7E:text=*.so%20is%20not%20valid%20WIN32%20application), for treesitter to work on windows it needs a few extra steps. In the link you will find the steps but in my opinion just use WSL and run LazyVim in there, it's gonna be much easier.